# mount error(5): Input/output error on mount using CIFS

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I have to mount a network drive(drive from a server) on my VM(ubuntu) & host is windows. For that I have used command in /etc/fstab like below:

`//xx.xx.xxx.xx/datacom /home/ubuntu/test cifs credentials=/home/ubuntu/.smbcredentials,sec=ntlm,vers=3.0 0 0`
When I hit command sudo mount -a it shows `mount error(5): Input/output error`. I followed steps from below link: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/map-network-drive-onto-ubuntu-14-04/

But still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share the output of `mount --verbose -t cifs //xx.xx.xxx.xx/datacom /home/ubuntu/test -o credentials=/home/ubuntu/.smbcredentials,sec=ntlm,vers=3.0`? `journalctl` may also have useful information.

Comment: vers=2.0 worked for me.First, we need to check SMB version on host OS in power shell using commands like: 

`>Set-SmbServerConfiguration –EnableSMB2Protocol $true OR 
> Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB2ProtocolGet-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB2Protocol OR
>Get-SmbConnection'